# Как завершить авторизацию через curl что далее уже был авторизован пользователь?

Tags: php, opencart

```
<?php

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$curl = curl_init();
$data = "{\n \"login\": \"$login\",\n  \"password\": \"$password\"\n}";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://test.test.org/api/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Как завершить авторизацию через curl что далее уже был авторизован пользователь?

Как с массива полученного в ответ сохранять данные в отдельные переменные? в формате json приходит массив

Answer (score 0):

Судя по url **https://test.test.org/api/token** вам приходит токен, который вы дальше должны использовать в запросах для *https://test.test.org/api* в качестве headers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers) или параметра в запросах. Это зависит от спецификации вашего API https://test.test.org/api/token.

Comment: День добрый, спасибо а зависит ли это если я беру пользователей с другого сайта и бд которых нету в моей бд? и токен так же от туда получаю
Это типа общая база и через нее авторизацию хочу сделать(шина так сказать)

Comment: @Bistore.bi-group, да зависит, у вас 2 разные системы. Т.е. как я вижу решение:

1. Добавить в БД сайта
2. Авторизировать пользователя (https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/cart/user.php)

Если у вас opencart как я вижу по тегу

Comment: я получаю в посте только токен и код сотрудника и после по коду достать данные имя почту и токен как ключ используя внести его в бд ? и посте по токену уже в хедере пользователя смотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала сделайте

```
$array=json_decode($response,true);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($array);
```

Там посмотрите что возвращается и где. Например токен будет $array['response']['token'], вот и сохраняйте его как удобнее - в сессии, куке, БД и используйте в дальнейших запросах.